# python help pulling info out of a file

Tags: python-3.x, search

I am trying to parse some data in a file and getting stuck:

Here is my code:

```
import re
        
with open('slo_id.txt', "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    # pattern = re.compile(r"'id':")
    # matches = pattern.finditer(lines)
    # for match in matches:
    #     print(matches)
    #f.close()
    for line in lines:
        item = re.findall("\s'id':.*$",lines,re.MULTILINE)
        for l in item:
            print(l.strip())
    f.close()
```

The comments are other things I have tried.

This is a sample of what I am trying to parse

```
{'data': [{'created_at': 1623855546,
           'creator': {'email': 'some_email',
                       'handle': 'some_handle',
                       'name': 'a_name'},
           'description': 'description',
           'id': '0eb2a314c6cc54fba2d7fc9e67c6d684',
           'modified_at': 1623856440,
           'monitor_ids': [35763088],
           'monitor_tags': [],
           'name': 'name',
           'tags': [tags],
           'thresholds': [{'target': 99.0,
                           'target_display': '99.',
                           'timeframe': '30d',
                           'warning': 99.89,
                           'warning_display': '99.89'}],
           'type': 'monitor'},
```

I know the file is saved as a json file, but it is not json, it is saved like this as I ran something else to pull data from an API call, which initially I thought was returning json, but it does not appear to be the case.  I am unsure if changing to a .txt file will make any difference.

My goal is that I want to find all of the lines with

```
  'id': 'some ID'
```

and cut the 'id' part out so it only prints the actual id and I can then send that to a new file.  I am at a point with this where the code runs, but nothing outputs and I am lost as I am very new to coding.

Any help is appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the IDs in one swoop:

```
text = """{'data': [{'created_at': 1623855546,
           'creator': {'email': 'some_email',
                       'handle': 'some_handle',
                       'id': 'xycvbn14c6cc54fba2d7fc9e67c6d684',
                       'name': 'a_name'},
           'description': 'description',
           'id': '0eb2a314c6cc54fba2d7fc9e67c6d684',
           'modified_at': 1623856440,
           'monitor_ids': [35763088],
           'monitor_tags': [],
           'name': 'name',
           'tags': [tags],
           'thresholds': [{'target': 99.0,
                           'target_display': '99.',
                           'timeframe': '30d',
                           'warning': 99.89,
                           'warning_display': '99.89'}],
           'type': 'monitor'},"""

with open("k.txt","w") as f: 
    f.write(text)

import re

with open("k.txt") as f:
    all_ids = re.findall( r"'id': '[^']+'", f.read())

print(all_ids)
```

Output:

```
["'id': 'xycvbn14c6cc54fba2d7fc9e67c6d684'", "'id': '0eb2a314c6cc54fba2d7fc9e67c6d684'"]
```

The regex-pattern looks for literal `'id': '....'` where `....` is anything *but* a `'` and finds them all.

To get only the actual ids use a grouping `re.findall( r"'id': '([^']+)'", f.read())`:

```
['xycvbn14c6cc54fba2d7fc9e67c6d684', '0eb2a314c6cc54fba2d7fc9e67c6d684']
```

You can then store the things from the list as you like.